# Meshgrid and confusion regarding X and Y coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
def L2Norm(f, x, y, d=0.00001):
    dudx = (f(x+d,y) - f(x-d,y)) / (2*d) 
    dudy = (f(x,y+d) - f(x,y-d)) / (2*d)
    L2Norm = np.float128(np.sqrt(dudx**2 + dudy**2))
return L2Norm

def f(x,y):
    return np.float128((1.0 + np.sin(np.pi*x))*((3.0 + np.cos(2.011*y))**2)*np.e**((-x**2)-((y**2)/4)))

# 20 points in X direction
x = np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,20)
# 40 points in Y direction
y = np.linspace(-2.0,2.0,40)
[X,Y] = np.meshgrid(x,y)
L2_Norm = L2Norm(f, X, Y)
print L2_Norm[37,13]
```

My function is above. Basically, I would expect to call the function L2Norm and get an array going from 0 to 19 in the X direction, or first index and 0 to 39 in the second.

Instead, it seems like the first index now corresponds to where I would expect y to be.

I can call
L2_Norm[39,19]
but not
L2_Norm[19,39]
Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `L2_Norm.shape`, you'll see that the dimensions of the array is (40,20) so as the error states, `L2_Norm[19,39]` is out of range because 39 > the max index in that dimension of 19. Take a look at the shape of `X` and `Y` as well to see why L2_Norm has the shape that it does -- the reason is clear if you look in the `meshgrid` documentation:

> For vectors x, y with lengths
>   Nx=len(x) and Ny=len(y), **return X, Y
>   where X and Y are (Ny, Nx) shaped
>   arrays** with the elements of x and y
>   repeated to fill the matrix along the
>   first dimension for x, the second for
>   y.

Comment: So if I understand you right, my L2 minimum (which is at L2_Norm[39,19])  The function at that point is f(X[37,13], Y[37,13])  ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the minimum. My answer only addresses why you get the index out of range error.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Don't mean to hassle you... and I goofed the numbers above. Basically, when I call L2_Norm[37,13] above, it's the same result as calling L2_Norm(f, X[37,13], Y[37,13])

Comment: That appears to be correct both from my check and the expected behavior of the code.